# VSCode doesn't track changes of a clone

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-clone

Just cloned my own repo from GitHub to a different PC

It's not tracking any changes. I tried switching branches, opening/closing repo, but it still doesn't track it.

I'm not using any terminal commands, just the VSCode interface. Normally every change is listed in the Source Control tab, but now it's not showing anything.

Do I need to take any extra steps after cloning a repo for source control to work?

When I start working on a new project locally and initialize locally, everything works - staging, commits, publish to Github etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the commands you've typed and the output you've received, and explain more clearly what you mean by "it does nothing".

Comment: @bk2204 not using any terminal commands. Question updated

Comment: What changes did you perform? Switching a branch is not something that needs committing. How did you clone the repo?

Comment: I added a folder with files, by dragging it from file explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Create a folder from VSCode and then paste your new files there. That automatically tracks all changes.

If you post them from outside (file explorer or finder), you need to `git add` them manually.